# excel collect data rolling from month to month

Tags: arrays, excel

I am currently using this array =SUMPRODUCT(--('sheet1'!$A:$A=C7),--('sheet1'!$G:$G="Lost")) to collect information on a 3rd sheet. I am trying to figure out how to only select data from the current month.  The dates are all on sheet1 Column B.  It would be appreciated some in site one how to move forward. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the beginning and end dates

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('sheet1'!$A:$A=C7)*('sheet1'!$G:$G="Lost")*('sheet1'!$B:$B>EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1))*('sheet1'!$B:$B<=EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)))
```

One note:

I used full column references as you had, but with array type formulas one should confine the reference to the cells with data and not use full column references.

With Array type formulas it will iterate trough the entire column, so this formula will do over 4 million calculations, most unneeded.  If you filled a column with this formula you would start to notice a lag in the calc times.